# Only extract digits with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-replace

I need to extract digits only (at least 2 but not more than 3) from an option text in a drop down list and get that shown in an input field. I've read about regexp (http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml) and thought i had it all figured out. But i just can't seem to get it to work.

```
<script>
function copyEbc() {
var a = document.getElementById("malt"); // the <select>
var onlydig = /\d{1,3}/ // regexp
var option = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text(onlydig); // regexp on options
var txt = document.getElementById("ebc").value;
txt = txt + option;
document.getElementById("ebc").value = txt;

}
</script>
```

Example, I only want "4" from a selected option with the text "Pilsner 4 EBC".

Am I completely lost here?

Input much appreciated, cheers

Comment: Try /^\d{3}$/ for your regex. This will get you 3 digits.

Comment: The joys of regular expressions, here's a nice quote to think about. "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call the `text` value as a function (your JS console has probably complained about this).

Match against the regular expression, instead. `match[0]` will contain the matched text:

```
var option = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text.match(onlydig)[0];
```

Comment: Well, new problem now: if I choose a new option in the list (eg. "Chocolate malt 800 EBC") it simply add the digits to the already selected digits from the earlier selection, and is now showing "4800". I want it the clear the field and add the digits from the new selection only. Is there a way around that?

Comment: `document.getElementById("ebc").value = option;`

Answer (score 0):

to simply extract the number(s) from a string use `match`:

```
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
var foo = 'Pilsner 4 EBC';
var numbers = foo.match(numberPattern);
alert(numbers); // alerts the array of numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "match" method of the regexp object. AFAIK the "text" method you are using do not exist.